# Clean SurfaceTexture with black rect

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-textureview

I'm using **Exoplayer** and an **GL SurfaceTexture** (from a TextureView) to display a video. I'm **reusing the same surface** among video play.

I release the player and instantiate a new one. When the SurfaceTexture is displayed the second time, **it display the old Texture from last video** until the player begin to play and fill the Surface with black.

I'm looking for a way to **draw a black rect to fill the surface** with black, but unable to achieve this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using @fadden link on Grafika, I've made my own script to clear the surface. It's compatible from API 16.

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/5ca05821444353a823bb)

```
/**
 * Clear the given surface Texture by attaching a GL context and clearing the surface.
 * @param texture a valid SurfaceTexture
 */
private void clearSurface(SurfaceTexture texture) {
    if(texture == null){
        return;
    }

    EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
    EGLDisplay display = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    egl.eglInitialize(display, null);

    int[] attribList = {
            EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL10.EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
            EGL10.EGL_NONE, 0,      // placeholder for recordable [@-3]
            EGL10.EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
    int[] numConfigs = new int[1];
    egl.eglChooseConfig(display, attribList, configs, configs.length, numConfigs);
    EGLConfig config = configs[0];
    EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, new int[]{
            12440, 2,
            EGL10.EGL_NONE
    });
    EGLSurface eglSurface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, texture,
            new int[]{
                    EGL10.EGL_NONE
            });

    egl.eglMakeCurrent(display, eglSurface, eglSurface, context);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    egl.eglSwapBuffers(display, eglSurface);
    egl.eglDestroySurface(display, eglSurface);
    egl.eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE,
            EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
    egl.eglDestroyContext(display, context);
    egl.eglTerminate(display);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, its working now. One have to import `javax.microedition.khronos.egl.*` imports.

Comment: This only worked on the first transition for me. All the subsequent transitions came back with `E/libEGL: eglCreateWindowSurface: native_window_api_connect failed (already connected to another API?)`

Comment: @AndyM: the error indicates that something is already attached to the SurfaceTexture. The player needs to detach from SurfaceTexture before GLES can attach.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Exoplayer, but I suspect your options are the same as for playback with MediaPlayer, listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009210/texture-view-video-and-bitmap-display/29014350#29014350).

Summary:

- You can attach GLES, clear the Surface, detach GLES ([Grafika does this](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java#L246)).
- You can create a one-frame black video and play it.
- You can create a second, empty View that overlays the first. Hide it while the video is playing, and show it when the video is done.

What you can't do is attach a Canvas and clear it, because once a Canvas is attached it never lets go.

Comment: Grafika `clearSurface` and sub class use min API 17 for many function such as `EglCore#makeCurrent`. I'm targetting API 16 :/ 
The other method is really not the way I want to do it.

Comment: API 17 is needed for EGL 1.4. You can replace the functions with EGL 1.0 equivalents, since you don't need anything 1.4-specific to simply clear the screen. See http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest for an example of the same code written for both versions of EGL.

Comment: u_U I was trying to do it with Canvas but apparently "The trouble is that there is no way to detach a software-based (Canvas) buffer producer." says http://stackoverflow.com/a/24914966/1377145

Comment: So I've read http://stackoverflow.com/a/29243067/1377145 and made my own script for API min 16 : https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/5ca05821444353a823bb

Comment: I suggest you to include one of the link or I will post it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please call

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

before draw new frame

Comment: It missing the attach context part to the previously used surface

Answer (score 0):

[Super Example code](https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/5ca05821444353a823bb)

Definitely works for clearing SurfaceView,
used like that:

```
if (player != null) {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
            }

    if (binding.surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {
                try {
                    clearSurface(binding.surfaceView);
                }catch (RuntimeException re){
                    re.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```